# authenticate with Spring saml security

Tags: spring, saml

Our spring boot project has multiple SPs and each one has its own IDP.
We want to know if it is possible to realize the anthentication with Spring Saml.
We have already realized it with One SP and IDP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  We have this setup in our application.  You'll need to override several of the SAML basic services to do this though.  In particular:

- CachingMetadataManager (mostly around getDefaultIDP and
  getEntityDescriptor)
- SAMLEntryPoint , to route your different SPs to
  the correct IDP.  Also if you have different options for your IDPs you can fix that here.
- SAMLContextProvider , to assign your SP Entity IDs

Comment: Can you kindly offer us some example about the implementation?